# Strange behaviour between Power BI and Snowflake

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We see a strange error when connecting Power BI to Snowflake. This error appears when we try to add a table within a schema containing an underscore (_) in the name.

For example: "LAB_PRJ_S4_GTS"."DATA_API"."CUSTOMS_CLASSIFICATION_API"

We get error "DataSource.Error: The table has no visible columns and cannot be queried.". After investigation, it appears that the instruction sent to Snowflake is:

```
show /* ODBC:ColumnMetadataSource */ columns in table "LAB_PRJ_S4_GTS"."DATA\_API"."CUSTOMS_CLASSIFICATION_API"
```

As you can see, instead of `DATA_API`, it reads `DATA\_API`. It looks like the ODBC driver considers _ as a special character, and then tries to escape it.

In Snowflake Query History, we get that error: `SQL compilation error: Schema 'LAB_PRJ_S4_GTS."DATA\_API"' does not exist or not authorized.`

Some additional info:

- We use latest version of Power BI Desktop (August 21 version)
- We use the latest version of Snowflake ODBC driver (not sure if it's used by Power BI or not)
- We use the Power BI Snowflake Connector

But why does Snowflake have issue with that ?

Thanks a lot for your help !!

Comment: Are you using ODBC or the Power BI Snowflake Connector? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-snowflake

Comment: This is an issue at client side, so either Power BI or the connector. I would expect this to be a common issue, so please check the versions you are using and test with latest one to check. Please share details of your connector if it still happens.

Comment: I don't know why the driver is escaping the underscore, but I can tell you that Snowflake has issues with it, because it uses double-quoted object names to allow for special characters, so it doesn't use \ as an escape in that situation.  I would see whether the latest Snowflake Connector for PowerBI has the same behavior.

Comment: I've adjusted the description based on your comments. We use the Power BI Snowflake Connector, and latest versions of both Power BI Desktop and ODBC driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody faces the same situation, here is the solution. We found out that this behaviour was related to account parameter `ODBC_SCHEMA_CACHING` which was set to `TRUE`.

This resolved the situation for us:
`ALTER ACCOUNT SET ODBC_SCHEMA_CACHING=FALSE`

Once done, Power BI or Excel (via ODBC) started to behave as expected, with no error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is working as expected because with the connectors like JDBC and ODBC, the underscore has to be used with escape character which is "". So, try to add the schema like this:

```
"LAB_PRJ_S4_GTS"."DATA\_API"."CUSTOMS_CLASSIFICATION_API"
```

and then see if it works fine.

Comment: Yes, that's indeed what I think and also what is sent to Snowflake. But the escape character is not unescaped by the ODBC driver prior to communicating with Snowflake. Instruction received in Snowflake is `show columns in table "LAB_PRJ_S4_GTS"."DATA\_API"."CUSTOMS_CLASSIFICATION_API"`